# Trying to make WordPress ignore the first dots in a file URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I've been trying to fix this for days.

A URL like this `/uploads/2022/07/my file_519-xvdfdg.mp4.0000.jpg` issue is the presence of multiple periods (..)

The actual file name has the dots.

How do I make it ignore the first two periods and treat the file as `.jpg`.

Currently I am getting a 415 error.

Answer (score 2):

> trying to make wordpress ignore the first dots

To clarify, this isn't a WordPress problem, WordPress is most likely already "ignoring" this file entirely.

The issue is probably the multiple file extensions and so Apache is perhaps returning (or expecting to return) a different Content-Type than what has been requested. eg. the browser has requested image/jpeg, but Apache wants to send it as video/mp4.

You can try forcing the "correct" mime-type for these requests.

You could perhaps create an additional `.htaccess` file in the `/uploads` directory just for this purpose, or modify the existing `.htaccess` file in the document root. These directives must be outside of the `# BEGIN WordPress` - `# END WordPress` section.

For example:

```
<FilesMatch "\.jpg$">
    ForceType image/jpeg
</FilesMatch>
```